# instanceof for template types in java

Tags: java, templates, instanceof

How can i determine if an object is instance of a parametrized type of a generic class for example `ArrayList<String>`? I tried:

```
if(obj instanceof ArrayList<String>)
```

but it failed with compiler error!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, you can't/shouldn't do this, due to **type erasure**. **Parametrized types exist as such only up to compilation and not during runtime. So you can't have type safety ensured by generics and parametrized types at runtime.** They are there to ensure type safety while programming, but all such type information is gone by the time the program is running, as types are substituted as appropriate and what you are left with are non-parametrized normal classes. At best, you can do something like this:

```
obj instanceof ArrayList
```

to check whether `obj` is an instance of `ArrayList` and:

```
obj.get(0) instanceof String
```

to check whether the stored objects in the `ArrayList` are instances of `String`. Of course, you might want to check whether there are any elements first.

Alternatively, you could use reflection (see for example [getActualTypeArguments()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html#getActualTypeArguments%28%29) from the ParametrizedType interface).

Comment: Clever solution but you know may be the list is empty!

Comment: It should go without saying that a size check should be done first. But I've added that to the answer.

Comment: Of course you could still do it with reflection. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403909/get-generic-type-of-class-at-runtime/3404169#3404169 and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html#getActualTypeArguments%28%29.  But keep in mind that doing this is probably a sign of (very) bad design.

Answer (score 1):

Because There won't be any Generics at run time in java. So Compiler won't allow this logic.